# Recursive query to obtain dependencies from a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a structure of 3 columns called DEPENDENCIES:

```
CREATE TABLE [LOG].[DEPENDENCIES]
(
    [DEPENDENCY_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PROCESS_ID_PARENT] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PROCESS_ID_CHILD] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

`Process_Id_Child` is dependent on `Process_Id_Parent`. In some cases the dependency can have many levels but so far I have only been able to obtain up to the second level of dependency with the following query:

```
SELECT
    PAR_PACK.PROCESS_ID AS PARENT_PROCESS_ID,
    PAR_PACK.PACKAGE_NAME AS PARENT_PACKAGE_NAME, 
    P.PROCESS_ID,  
    P.PACKAGE_NAME,  
    CHI_PACK.PROCESS_ID AS CHILD_PROCESS_ID, 
    CHI_PACK.PACKAGE_NAME AS CHILD_PACKAGE_NAME
FROM
    PROCESSES P 
LEFT JOIN 
    DEPENDENCIES PAR ON P.PROCESS_ID = PAR.PROCESS_ID_CHILD 
LEFT JOIN 
    PROCESSES PAR_PACK ON PAR.PROCESS_ID_PARENT = PAR_PACK.PROCESS_ID 
LEFT JOIN 
    DEPENDENCIES CHI ON P.PROCESS_ID = CHI.PROCESS_ID_PARENT 
LEFT JOIN 
    PROCESSES CHI_PACK ON CHI.PROCESS_ID_CHILD = CHI_PACK.PROCESS_ID
```

The `PROCESSES` table helps me get the name of the Process being executed. The `Process ID` is also present in the `PROCESSES` table.

What would be the best method to obtain dependencies at all levels?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a _recursive common table expression_? Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Sample input???  Expected output???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It would be easier with some sample data, however I'll attempt without it:

You will want to create a [Common Expression Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) with two statements separated with a [UNION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

The first expression in your CTE is your Anchor. This expression alone should return all Parent Nodes. Below, I assumed a parent ID with NULL would be sufficient. Again, without sample data I can't test.

The second expression in your CTE (After your union) is your Members. It will SELECT FROM your CTE then join your tables to find the children. This iterates all levels from the parent to child until the return set is not a parent to the inner joined table.

I added [lvl] to show how deep it goes down the hierarchy and [PATH] which is a good method to get everything in the proper order.

If it doesn't work, it points you in the right direction. If it doesn't work and you post sample data, I will edit it appropriately.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        PAR_PACK.PROCESS_ID AS PARENT_PROCESS_ID,
        PAR_PACK.PACKAGE_NAME AS PARENT_PACKAGE_NAME, 
        P.PROCESS_ID,  
        P.PACKAGE_NAME,  
        CHI_PACK.PROCESS_ID AS CHILD_PROCESS_ID, 
        CHI_PACK.PACKAGE_NAME AS CHILD_PACKAGE_NAME,
        1 AS [lvl], 
        CAST(CONVERT(nvarchar(10),PAR_PACK.PROCESS_ID) + '-->' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10),CHI_PACK.PROCESS_ID) as nvarchar(max)) as PATH
    FROM
        PROCESSES P 
    LEFT JOIN 
        DEPENDENCIES PAR ON P.PROCESS_ID = PAR.PROCESS_ID_CHILD 
    LEFT JOIN 
        PROCESSES PAR_PACK ON PAR.PROCESS_ID_PARENT = PAR_PACK.PROCESS_ID 
    LEFT JOIN 
        DEPENDENCIES CHI ON P.PROCESS_ID = CHI.PROCESS_ID_PARENT 
    LEFT JOIN 
        PROCESSES CHI_PACK ON CHI.PROCESS_ID_CHILD = CHI_PACK.PROCESS_ID
    WHERE PAR_PACK.PACKAGE_NAME IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        c.PARENT_PROCESS_ID,
        c.PARENT_PACKAGE_NAME, 
        c.PROCESS_ID,  
        c.PACKAGE_NAME,  
        c.CHILD_PROCESS_ID, 
        c.CHILD_PACKAGE_NAME,
        [lvl] = p.lvl + 1,
        PATH + '-->' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10),CHI_PACK.PROCESS_ID ) 
    FROM CTE c
    INNER JOIN DEPENDENCIES PAR ON c.PROCESS_ID = PAR.PROCESS_ID_CHILD 
    INNER JOIN PROCESSES P ON P.PROCESS_ID = PAR.PROCESS_ID_CHILD 
    LEFT JOIN 
        PROCESSES PAR_PACK ON PAR.PROCESS_ID_PARENT = PAR_PACK.PROCESS_ID 
    LEFT JOIN 
        DEPENDENCIES CHI ON P.PROCESS_ID = CHI.PROCESS_ID_PARENT 
    LEFT JOIN 
        PROCESSES CHI_PACK ON CHI.PROCESS_ID_CHILD = CHI_PACK.PROCESS_ID
)
SELECT * FROM CTE ORDER BY PATH
```